# Did a Milwaukee airport allow Biden but not Trump to hold a rally because Biden's rally will be smaller?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump, joe-biden

A [twitchy article](https://twitchy.com/dougp-3137/2020/10/30/joe-biden-allowed-to-hold-event-at-same-milwaukee-airport-that-denied-trump-a-rally-guess-why/) claims that Mitchell International Airport will allow Biden to hold a rally but not Trump because the former rally is significantly smaller:

> The Trump campaign was denied a permit to hold a rally at Milwaukee’s Mitchell International Airport.
>
> "...holding any large special event that is non-aeronautical in nature would be a violation of its lease."
>
> However, Joe Biden will be allowed to hold an event at the same airport. And why is that?
>
> "Biden's rally will be much, much smaller than Trump's."

Is this claim accurate?

EDIT: Sorry for asking the question.

Comment: It seems from the link that it is Dan O'Donnell of the Dan O'Donnell Show who is calling Biden's private meeting a "rally", presumably to cause dissent. I really admire that skill – the ability to conjure up things that don't exist.

Comment: Why did you get all those downvotes?

Comment: @LeoR some questions are just better than others I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that the Biden event is not a rally but a small meeting

https://www.tmj4.com/news/election-2020/airport-officials-explain-reasoning-behind-allowing-biden-event-after-denying-previous-trump-event

> "The Airport does not allow political rallies on the airfield, regardless of which candidate requests it. Biden is hosting a small private meeting with about 12 people. This is the difference between a 12-person private meeting inside a building vs. a 20,000-person rally on the airfield, compromising the safety and security of airline operations," said Harold Mester, director of public affairs and marketing for the airport.
>
> Vice President Joe Biden is holding a small, private meeting at AvFlight, which operates a private aircraft terminal at Milwaukee Mitchell International Airport. Meeting organizers are aware that Wisconsin is a COVID-19 hotspot and have indicated that the meeting will include a small number of invited guests and staff well below the City of Milwaukee’s limit on gatherings of this type.
>
> The meeting is not open to the public and will occur inside AvFlight’s facility, and attendees will not have access to the airfield. Airline operations will not be affected, and this facility does not have direct access to any commercial air service runway. The permitting of this visit is not an endorsement for any political party or candidate for office by the County Executive in his official capacity.
>
> In addition, the permitting of this visit is not politically motivated as numerous political visits to General Mitchell from both parties that did not disrupt Airport operations or pose a public health risk have been allowed in the past.